# Test Automation Selenium - Chrome Driver 84.xx opens with "data" but not launching application URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch an application URL using Test automation with Selenium webdriver and using chrome driver version 84.0.4147.30 which is the correct driver for the actual chrome version in my organization (ver 84.0.4147.105). This is been checked in Chrome driver website. But the chrome driver launches the browser with "data" and after that fails to load or navigate to the URL. Not sure what the reason for this is. Please find the attached screenshot[image]

The same activity successfully works with firefox driver and no issues at all.

By the way, the actual chrome which we are using in the company has got "Managed by the organisation" message when we access settings of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your chrome browser version and use to download https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads  link for latest chrome driver exe refresh project and rerun (set your path also correct)